# pass a string in argument to create a .csv in PHP

Tags: php, string, csv

I want to edit a .csv by adding a string at the end of the original .csv then download the new .csv created with PHP,

my code is:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


$file = fopen("csv.csv","r");
$list = array();

while(! feof($file))
  {
      $list[] = (fgetcsv($file));
  }
fclose($file);



$CSV = 'name5:SEPARATOR1:town5:SEPARATOR2:name6:SEPARATOR1:town6:SEPARATOR2:name6:SEPARATOR1:town6:SEPARATOR2:';

$csv_array = explode(":SEPARATOR2:", $CSV);

for($i=0;$i<count($csv_array)-1;$i++){
    $temp = explode(":SEPARATOR1:", $csv_array[$i]);
    $list[] = array($temp[0],$temp[1]);
}

$list = array_filter($list);
outputCSV($list);

function outputCSV($list) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

but I want the string $CSV to be created dynamically from an other page.
It's possible with the GET function but $CSV will be too long.
I tried with ajax, but without success.
Any one has an idea please?

Comment: is file from your domain, can't you just include it. Otherwise try [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: I had a look on curl but I don't get how it can help me here

Comment: i'm so stupid, it's super easy with $_SESSION!!!!!!